# Me salta directamente al Else

Tags: javascript, html, if, else

tengo que ingresar dos numeros y me tiene que decir si son par o impar. Esta a medio hacer pero lo pruebo y me salta directamente el alert del else, sin importar si los numeros son pares o no.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function comprobar() {

    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");

    if (num1 % 2 == 0 && num2 % 2 == 0) {
      alert('par');
    } else {
      alert('impar');
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<input type="button" id="boton" value="comprobar" onclick="comprobar()">
```

Comment: Que valores estas introduciendo? Porque lo he probado y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Solo como referencia, mira el [tour] y tambien lee [ask]. Bienvenido!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tu problema esta en que estas obteniendo el elemento con `id` `num1` y `num2` pero no estas cogiendo su valor, si no el elemento del DOM entero, por eso te salta siempre al `else`. Te falta hacer un `.value` del elemento.

```js
  function comprobar() {

    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    if (num1 % 2 == 0 && num2 % 2 == 0) {
      alert('par');
    } else {
      alert('impar');
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<input type="button" id="boton" value="comprobar" onclick="comprobar()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es porque no cojes el valor de los números, si no que estás cogiendo el objeto html en sí, por tanto entra directamente en el else, porque no se da la condición del if, ya que un objeto html (el input id=num1") no es ni par ni impar.

Cambia esta linea `var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");` por esta `var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;`

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

#### Respuesta corta

Si ejecutas `console.log(num1);` podrás ver que te devuelve `<input id="num1" type="text">` y eso quiere decir que las variables `num1` y `num2` son etiquetas HTML, **no sus valores**. Para obtener los valores que ingresas tu código debería quedar así:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
```

#### En profundidad

Cuando obtienes elementos del `DOM`, con alguna de las funciones como `getElementById()` o `getElementByClass()` obtienes un nodo, un elemento HTML.

Este nodo es un objeto con sus métodos y propiedades. Puedes establecer las propiedades que quieras al nodo HTML, por ejemplo en este caso:

```
num1.foo = "bar";
console.log(num1.foo); // Devuelve "bar"
```

La mayoría de navegadores tienen herramientas para inspeccionar el árbol de nodos HTML. Si inspeccionamos un elemento `<input>` podemos ver que tiene propiedades `value` o `innerHTML` donde se guardan los valores que ingresamos dentro de nuestra página.

Comment: si completas tu respuesta sera bien visto por la comunidad

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el value en las dos líneas en dónde recoges los valores:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
```

Y te funcionará.